# PHP simply use strpos doesn't work correctly

Tags: php

In php I want to simply find the percent in string value such as `33%`. This below code works fine:

```
echo strpos("%", '33%') == true
    ? '33%'
    : '33' . '$';
```

but then when I put this percent into a variable, `strpos()` it doesn't work correctly, for example:

```
$move_money_data = '33%';
echo strpos("%", $move_money_data) == true
    ? $move_money_data
    : $move_money_data . '$';
```

I think the code is correct, but I don't know why when I put it into a variable, the result is not correct.

Comment: It's important to note that strpos() never returns true so comparing it to true is a bad practice.  It either returns false or an integer representing the position of the string in the haystack.  Therefore you should use `!== false` instead of `== true` to do a strict comparison on it not being false otherwise, when it returns 0, it will equate to false, not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong order in strpos

```
$move_money_data = '33';
echo strpos($move_money_data, '%' ) === false ? ($move_money_data . '$') : $move_money_data;
```

//EDIT
from php.net

```
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

Comment: i can't understand me whats difference between your code and `echo strpos($move_money_data, '%' ) === true ? $move_money_data:($move_money_data . '$');`

Comment: the strpos is returning false if it did not found needle. It never returns true only int. So you should avoid checking if it is true

Comment: Thanks, i'm understand